# What exactly did Margaret lie about?

Tags: plot-explanation, suburbicon

In [*Suburbicon* (2017)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0491175/), insurance police officer Bud Cooper claims Margaret lies to him.

> **Cooper:** You said "we". "We lost our savings when Gardner tried to start his own business". "We lost our", not "they lost their".
>
> **Margaret:** I think you should leave before I call the police.

Comment: From your quoted dialogue it's not quite clear to me how Roger accuses Margaret of lieing. Can you add a little more context about the scene to clarify what exact parts of the story you're unclear about or can't bring in relation to that dialogue?

Answer (score 1):

Margaret, if you recall, was trying to take on the role of her sister Rose, to the point of dyeing her hair blonde and having sex with Gardner.  Gardner had enlisted help to kill Rose, and it's presumed that Margaret was part of the plan.  Upon being questioned, Margaret speaks *as if she is Rose*, a fatal slip-up which Cooper pounces on.  He had suspected all along that they had conspired to murder Rose.  It was at this point where Margaret asks Cooper to leave.